# Include logo in thesis using \maketitle

Tags: titles, front-matter, logos

I'm writing my thesis using a custom made class, namely ecsthesis.cls (available here https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/university-of-southampton-thesis/). I want to include the university logo in order to have something like [image]

I'm using \maketitle to make the frontpage which from the .cls should be

```
    \renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \bigskip
      {\normalsize \FACNAME \par}
      \smallskip
      {\normalsize \deptname \par}
      \vfill
  \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
  {\large \bf \@title \par}
      \bigskip
      {\Large by \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large \textbf{\authornames} \par}
      \vfill
      {\large Thesis for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\par}

      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
```

How can I redefine it in order to include the logo?

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}      % Use the Thesis Style
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[sort &compress]{natbib}  % Use Natbib style for the refs.\part{title}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{reaction}{chapter}
%\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\usepackage{caption}      
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tipa}
%\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

%

%
\setlength\epigraphwidth{8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}








\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title      {Three years wasted}

\authors    {\texorpdfstring
             {\href{ciao@ecs.soton.ac.uk}{Mickey Mouse}}
             {Mickey Mouse}
            }
\department  {}
\group       {}
\addresses  {\groupname\\\deptname\\\univname}
\date       {\today}
\subject    {}
\keywords   {}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
blablabla

\end{abstract}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\cleardoublepage
%% -----------------------
%% lstpatch.sty
%% -----------------------
%% lstpatch cannot be distributed with these files. I believe it is only needed if the
%% \lstlistoflistings is used. So this has been turned off by default. Re-add if required:
%% \usepackage{lstpatch}
%% \lstlistoflistings
%% You will need to download lstpatch, possibly from:
%% http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/listings/lstpatch.sty
%% -----------------------
% -----------------------
% Authorship declaration
% -----------------------
% Either include citations like below (as many as required spaced with commas or 'and').
\authorshipdeclaration{}
% Or state no citations like below
% \authorshipdeclaration{}

\mainmatter


\include{Introduction}

\include{LitteratureRewiev}


\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ECS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes, it is better to drop the titlepage command and build that page uding the usual commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find the proper `ecsthesis.cls`. Hence my tests may not be reliable. However, the following may be helpful:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\\[2em]               %% change 2em as needed
       \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}\par}        %% note includegraphics, logo is the file name of logo    
      \bigskip
      {\normalsize \FACNAME \par}
      \smallskip
      {\normalsize \deptname \par}
      \vfill
  \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
  {\large \bf \@title \par}
      \bigskip
      {\Large by \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large \textbf{\authornames} \par}
      \vfill
      {\large Thesis for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\par}

      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
\makeatother
```

You may have to adjust the spacings properly.

Comment: @Harnish it work, I just adjusted the position of the logo under the \faculty name.

Comment: @MicheleCarboni Glad it worked. :)